# Sum of cell above and cell to the left

Tags: google-sheets

Don't know if it's the right place, but please help me if possible.

Google Sheets. I need a formula for the sum of value in cell directly above and cell directly to the left. I've tried something like this, but it doesn't work:
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()), ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN()-1)))

Answer (score 1):

Try `OFFSET`: e.g. for cell B2:

`=OFFSET(B2,-1,0)+OFFSET(B2,0,-1)`

N.B. it fails if the values in those cells are not numeric.